# Pyspark Streaming with checkpointing is failing

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am working on spark streaming data received through custom receiver using pyspark. To make it fault tolerant I enabled checkpointing . Since then the code which was running fine before checkpointing was introduced is now throwing error.

Error Message :

```
    pubsubStream.flatMap(lambda x : x).map(lambda x: convertjson(x)).foreachRDD(lambda rdd : dstream_to_rdd(rdd))
  File "/home/test/spark_checkpointing/spark_checkpoint_test.py", line 227, in dstream_to_rdd
    df = spark_session.read.option("multiline","true")\
NameError: name 'sparkContext' is not defined
```

Code is as below :

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pubsub import PubsubUtils
import json
import time
from pyspark.sql.types import (StructField, StringType, StructType, IntegerType, FloatType,LongType,BooleanType)
from google.cloud import storage
import pyspark
conf_bucket_name = <bucket_name>

#Events list 
events_list = ["Event1","Event2"]


# This chunk of schema creation will be automated later
# and most probable moved outside

full_schema = StructType([
        StructField('_id', StructType([
             StructField('_data', StringType(), True)
             ])),
        StructField('ct', StructType([
             StructField('$timestamp' , StructType([
                    StructField('i', LongType(), True),
                    StructField('t', LongType(), True),
                    ]))])),
        StructField('fg', StructType([
             StructField('sgs' , StructType([
                    StructField('col1',StringType(), True),
                    StructField('col2',StringType(), True)
                    ]))])),
        StructField('col6', StringType(), True),
        StructField('_corrupt_record', StringType(), True)
    ])
    
def convertjson(ele):
    temp = json.loads(ele.decode('utf-8'))
    if temp['col6'] == 'update':
        del temp['updateDescription']
        return temp
    return temp

def dstream_to_rdd(x):
    if not x.isEmpty():

        df = spark_session.read.option("multiline","true")\
                           .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")\
                           .option("primitivesAsString", "false")\
                           .schema(full_schema)\
                           .option("columnNameOfCorruptRecord", "_corrupt_record")\
                           .option("allowFieldAddition","true")\
                           .json(x)

        df.show(truncate=True)
        #df.printSchema()
            
def createContext(all_config):
    # If you do not see this printed, that means the StreamingContext has been loaded
    # from the new checkpoint
    print("Creating new context")
    ssc = StreamingContext(spark_session.sparkContext, 10)
    pubsubStream = PubsubUtils.createStream(ssc, <SUBSCRIPTION>, 10000, True)
    
    # Print the records of dstream
    pubsubStream.pprint()            /// Dstreams are getting printed on console

    #Dstream is transforme using flatmap to flatten it as tuple may have multiple records
    #Then converted it to json forma and finally pushed to BQ
    pubsubStream.flatMap(lambda x : x).map(lambda x: convertjson(x)).foreachRDD(lambda rdd : dstream_to_rdd(rdd)) 
    
    pubsubStream.checkpoint(50)
    return ssc
    



if __name__ == "__main__":
    #Declaration of spark session and streaming session
    checkpointDir = <checkpointdir path on google cloud storage>
    spark_session = SparkSession.builder.appName("Test_spark_checkpoint").getOrCreate()
    spark_session.conf.set('temporaryGcsBucket', <temp bucket name>)
    ssc = StreamingContext.getOrCreate(checkpointDir,lambda: createContext(all_config))
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

The error message is of sparkContext not defined. On doing `dir(spark_session)`  this I found
that it returns list of the attributes and methods which contains `sparkContext` . Am I suppose to pass it explicitly. What is the miss here?

Also help me understanding the position of checkpointing used in code is correct or not.

***Update piece of code*** : Tried with `sparkContext` instead of `sparkSession`

```
    conf = SparkConf()
    conf.setAppName("Test_spark_checkpoint")
    conf.set('temporaryGcsBucket', <temp bucket>)
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    print(dir(sc))
    ssc = StreamingContext.getOrCreate(checkpointDir,lambda: createContext(all_config))
```

```
        df = sc.read.option("multiline","true")\
                           .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")\
                           .option("primitivesAsString", "false")\
                           .schema(full_schema)\
                           .option("columnNameOfCorruptRecord", "_corrupt_record")\
                           .option("allowFieldAddition","true")\
                           .json(x)

        df.show(truncate=True)
```

Comment: If you look at the Python code in the docs, SparkSession is not used https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html

Comment: Also, `spark_session.read.json` is for reading JSON files from the filesystem, not invoking `.toDF` on an RDD

Comment: @OneCricketeer On Replacing spark session with spark Context . It throws error as _pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Moreover the Dstream data is in the format of nested json , that is the reason of spark session. Is it not the right way ? Could you please let me know what needs to be done to make this code running with checkpointing.

Comment: The first error makes sense because you cannot use the Spark objects within a clojure that is serialized to executors (your `dstream_to_rdd` function). That has nothing to do with checkpointing, so I'm not sure what code you had before that was working. Overall, I suggest you [find a Structured Streaming library that works with PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/pubsub-lite-for-your-streaming-applications), or maybe use DataFlow/Apache Beam's SparkRunner w/ PubSubIO